# How old is an email client based on what it puts in <META name=GENERATOR content=MSHTML.... version?

Tags: html, email, outlook, version, meta-tags

Given the following beginning of an HTML email body, how old is their version of Outlook? How can we determine the Outlook release date when we receive version numbers similar to these? (I assume this is Outlook or one of the variants like Windows Mail or Outlook Express).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<META content="MSHTML 6.00.6002.18332" name=GENERATOR>
<STYLE></STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY bgColor=#ffffff>
<DIV><FONT face=Arial size=2>...........
..............................
..............................
..............................
```

There is a unicode byte order marker at the beginning of the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not look like outlook at all.

Found this

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_%28layout_engine%29

http://www.webmasterworld.com/html/3147495.htm

indicating that it's the rendering engine from IE that geneerated this header.